# Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. Imports

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, native-base

I can't get rid of this error: `Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.`

This is ProductContainer.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, ActivityIndicator, FlatList } from 'react-native';
import { Container, Header, Item, Icon, Input, Text } from 'native-base';

import ProductList from './ProductList';

const data = require('../../assets/data/products.json');

const ProductContainer = () => {
    const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        setProducts(data);

        return () => {
            setProducts([]);
        };
    }, []);

    return (
        <Container>
            <Header searchBar rounded>
                <Item>
                    <Icon name="ios-search" />
                    <Input placeholder="Search" />
                </Item>
            </Header>
            <View>
                <Text>Product Container</Text>
                <View style={{ marginTop: 100 }}>
                    <FlatList
                        data={products}
                        numColumns={2}
                        renderItem={({ item }) => <ProductList key={item.id} item={item} />}
                        keyExtractor={(item) => item.name}
                    />
                </View>
            </View>
        </Container>
    );
};

export default ProductContainer;
```

and this is my App.js:

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { NativeBaseProvider } from 'native-base';

//Screens
import Header from './Shared/Header';
import ProductContainer from './screens/Products/ProductContainer';

export default function App() {
    return (
        <NativeBaseProvider>
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Header />
                <ProductContainer />
            </View>
        </NativeBaseProvider>
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
    },
});
```

Been stuck on this for days now, please help.

I tried checking my imports and exports but can't figure out where this error is rising from. I also tried putting ProductList in curly braces where I import it in ProductContainer.js but didn't work. I appreciate the help!

Comment: You don't need the `useEffect` call in this case, just initialize your `products` state to `data`: `const [products, setProducts] = useState(data);`

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried to enclose your `ProductList` component in parenthesis and then run your project?

Like this:

import { ProductList}  from './ProductList';

Comment: I have but it doesn't work unfortunately

Comment: Can you share your App.js file

Comment: otherwise, you can share your code with codesandbox.io so that I can rectified and let you know what exactly the error is.

Comment: I shared the App.js in the post!

Comment: import { ProductContainer}  from './screens/Products/ProductContainer' 
Try adding paranthesis for this because you have not added export default before const ProductContainer class, you have export that component at the end .
so, just do this { ProductContainer} in App.js file it will work

Comment: Unfortunately it hasn't worked :(